# Using map_int with length() / formals() combination

Tags: r

I am trying to get the number of arguments within a list of functions from a package using the map_int() function.

This seems to be the output I am looking for manually :

```
length(names(formals(add_count)))
```

But the problem is applying that series of functions using map() to automate this process and eventually return the top/least function with the highest/lowest number of arguments:

```
map(dplyr_functions, length(formals))
```

The above returns an "Error: Can't pluck from a closure" error

So far, this seems to work to return a list of the arguments of the list of functions:

```
map(dplyr_functions, formals)
```

But I'm having trouble getting the actual count as would return

```
length(formals(add_count))
```

Thank you so much for your guidance

Comment: How about `map(dplyr_functions, ~length(formals(.)))`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thank you so much Andrew. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short hand to do this with `compose` (which is also from `purrr`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(list(add_count, summarise), compose(length, formals))
```